# Intuition behind this low level number theory problem.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that if x is an odd integer and y is an even integer, $$ x^2 -2y^2 = 1 $$ can be written in the form $$n^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}m(m+1) $$

where m and n are integers.

This is part of a question from a STEP past paper (2013 II Q7). I have been stuck on it for quite a while and I fear that I am missing something, there has to be more to it that just trail and error however I don't see another way. Clearly on the RHS we have the sum of the first $m$ natural numbers but I don't see how to proceed from there. Originally I thought that if we let $ m = x-1 $ $$ 2y^2 = x^2 -1 \implies y^2 - \dfrac{(m+2)}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}m(m+1)$$
however I didn't get anywhere with this since I couldn't find a suitable substitution for $y$. I don't want to look at the solution and I fear that this question might just be something that you are supposed to do by inspection. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I think the transformation comes from letting $x=2m+1$.

Comment: How did you see that? They both represent hyperbolas I think, could we solve it by writing them in the form $$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $$ and seeing the transformation from the graph?

Comment: I’m missing something. What does it mean to say that an equation in $x$ and $y$ “can be written as” a different equation in $n$ and $m$?

Comment: I was not correct about $n$, so modified the comment. We get $2y^2=4m(m+1)$. But then $y$ is divisible by $2$, let $y=2n$. We get your equation (after cancellation).

Comment: @SteveKass the full question can be found here. https://gyazo.com/32d372d3a13039971d569e80e7be898f

Comment: @Loua, I still have no idea what “can be written as” means.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this counts as intuition, but your rearrangement $$2y^2 = x^2 - 1$$ immediately made me think: *difference of squares*. $$x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1).$$
We're given the parities of $x$ and $y$; $x$ is odd, so try writing $x = 2m+1$. You'll get $$2y^2 = (x-1)(x+1) = (2m)(2m+2) = 4m(m+1).$$
To get that factor of a half instead of the four, use the fact that $y = 2n$ is even.

Comment: Yeah completing the square was the obvious first step but from there all the substitutions I made didn't work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since $x$ is odd, write $x=2m+1$ so $2y^2=x^2-1=4m\left(m+1\right)$. Since $y$ is even, write $y=2n$ so $2y^2=8n^2$. Now divide by $8$ to get the required result. (Note that the question needn't have told us $x,\,y$ were respectively odd and even; the former fact follows from $x^2=2y^2+1$ being odd, and if $y$ were old we would have $4|x^2-3$, which no integer satisfies.)